# alternatives for multiple if else conditions to make it in single line - javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

In one function, i am checking couple of condition with multiple if else condition. I want to do with using ternary operator to make it single line. I am not able to configure it how to do that

```
if (!this.$route.params.prdKey) {
            this.prodData.prdKey = '';
        } else {
            this.prodData.prdKey = this.$route.params.prdKey;
        }
        if (!this.$route.params.version) {
            this.prodData.version = 1;
        } else {
            this.prodData.version = this.$route.params.version;
        }
        this.pageMode = this.$route.params.pageMode;
        this.getProductDetailsList();
        if (!this.isPrdAvailable) {
            this.getproductList();
        } else {
            this.loadMoreproducts();
        }
```

Any other approach is also ok for me. There are in other part where i am using this kind of if-else condition check multiple times. So, i can remove those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two ternary expressions here:

```js
this.prodData.prdKey = this.$route.params.prdKey ? this.$route.params.prdKey : '';
this.prodData.version = this.$route.params.version ? this.$route.params.version : 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

`||` can be used to alternate between two possibilities - if the left-hand side is truthy, it'll evaluate to it, otherwise it'll evaluate to the right-hand side.

```
this.prodData.prdKey = this.$route.params.prdKey || '';
this.prodData.version = this.$route.params.version || 1;
```

Comment: Note that if 0 is a valid value here, it will never show up b/c of the boolean coercion. You may want to use nullish coalescence instead: his.prodData.prdKey = this.$route.params.prdKey ?? '';

Comment: OP's current code is using `!` to test, so this should have the same result.